# can i use push method to add series of arrays to an array?

Tags: jquery, push

Below code:

```
var data = []; 
data.push(["New" ,7576]);
data.push(["Existing" ,465 ]);
```

are the same as:

```
var data3 = [ 
    ["New", 7576],       
    ["Existing", 465]
];
```

but can I use `.push` to do this:

```
var data3 = [
    [["New", 7576]],
    [["Existing", 465]]
];
```

Comment: `data.push([["New" ,7576]]);`? What would the point of this be?...

Comment: Push `["New", 7576]` to an empty array. Then you can push this empty array to `data3`. Repeat with `["Existing", 465]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

As any other expression, Javascript will resolve it from inside out. It will create the inner arrays, generate the object, and then perform the push.